# What is type and what is type constructor in scala

Tags: scala

I'm a bit confused about understanding of what `type` in `scala` means.

In documents I read that `List[Int]` is a type and List is a type constructor.

but what keyword `type` means when I write the following?

```
val ls: scala.collection.immutable.List.type = scala.collection.immutable.List
```

And how this `type` related to `type` that can be defined as a field in a trait for example.

Comment: `val x: Int = 1`, `Int` is the type of `x`.

You can use certain types (like `Int` or `String`) using literals (`1` or `2` for `Int` or `"James"` for `String`).

Type constructors are types that need other types to be built.

`List` or `Option` won't be a fully qualified type unless you pass another type to them (i.e. `List[Int]` or `Option[String]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what keyword type means when I write the following

`type` is a member defined on `object` in Scala.

Suppose you have a class and its companion object:

```
class Foo(a: String)

object Foo {
  def apply(a: String) = new Foo(a)
}
```

Now suppose you want to write a method that accepts the object `Foo` as an input. What's its type?

If you write this:

```
def someMethod(fooObj: Foo) = fooObj.apply("x") // doesn't compile
```

it's not going to compile. `Foo` refers to the type of an instance of the class (i.e. the one returned by `new Foo("x")` or `Foo("x")`). That's why objects have a `type` member that can refer to their own type:

```
def someMethod(fooObj: Foo.type) = fooObj.apply("x") // compiles!
```

---

In your specific example `List.type` is the type of the companion object of `List`. Here's a couple of examples that I hope will clarify what it means:

```
val listObj: List.type = List
val anEmptyList: List[Int] = listObj.empty[Int] // List()
val aListOfIntegers: List[Int] = listObj.range(1, 4) // List[(1, 2, 3)
```

> And how this type related to type that can be defined as a field in a trait for example.

The `type` keyword defines a type member. `.type` *is* a type member. Conceptually it's like every object in Scala has a type member named type, like this:

```
object Foo {
  type type = Foo
}
```

Obviously this won't compile, but it gives you an idea of what it may look like.

Answer (score 18):

In a scala `val` assignment like the above:

```
val name: Tpe = expression
```

`Tpe` is the type of the identifier `name`. Hence:

```
val x: List.type = List
```

The type of the `List` *object* (aka *List module* or *List companion*) is `List.type`. This indicates that it is a singleton. All of this is completely orthogonal to the concept of a *type constructor* in type theory.

### Type Constructors

In type theory, `List` (note: not the companion) is both a type (denoted `*`) and a type constructor (denoted `* -> *`) because when you supply a type argument to `List` (e.g. Int) then you have a type (i.e. `List[Int]`). Scala provides syntax for this construction. For example:

```
def foo[F[_]]: F[Int]
        ^^^^     ^^^
         |        + supply a type argument to F[_]  
         |
         + the type constructor F[_]
```

But you cannot really implement such a method unless you know more about `F`. For example, if there is a implicit `scalaz.Monad[F]`, you might use the `Monad.pure` value to construct your `F[Int]` like so:

```
def foo[F[_]: Monad]: F[Int] = Monad[F].pure(1)
```

#### In Scala

Scala does let you pass around `List` as a type constructor as a type parameter to such a method. For example:

```
scala> def foo[F[_]]: F[Int] = ???
foo: [F[_]]=> F[Int]

scala> lazy val x = foo[List]
x: List[Int] = <lazy>
```

However the `List` you are supplying in `foo[List]` is *not* the companion

Note the declaration of `foo` will result in the following warning:

```
<console>:11: warning: higher-kinded type should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.higherKinds visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import 
scala.language.higherKinds'
or by setting the compiler option -language:higherKinds.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.higherKinds for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       def foo[F[_]]: F[Int] = ???
               ^
```

Comment: +1. Not just answering the actual question asked, but you answered the "Type Constructor" question I had that caused Google to bring me here.

Answer (score 4):

In type-level programming you’d think of a List[+A] being a type constructor:

That is:

-List[+A] takes a type parameter (A),

-by itself it’s not a valid type, you need to fill in the A somehow - "construct the type",

-by filling it in with String you’d get List[String] which is a concrete type.

In Scala it is not valid to say something is of type List. Scala is more strict here, and won’t allow us to use just a List in the place of a type, as it’s expecting a real type - not a type constructor.

In brief:
List[+A] is a type constructor whereas List[String] is a real type.